# Applying for an Italy Schengen visa from the Italian Consulate in Belfast

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, northern-ireland

I am a PhD student studying here in Northern Ireland, UK on a Tier 4 visa. I am an Indian national. I have to visit Italy to attend a conference. Can I apply for a Schengen visa through the Italian Consulate in Belfast?

Answer (score 7):

The Italian Consulate in Belfast is an Honorary Consulate, with limited hours and limited services.

According to the [site of the Italian Consulate in Edinburgh](http://www.consedimburgo.esteri.it/Consolato_Edimburgo/Menu/I_Servizi/Visti_per_recarsi_in_Italia/) (which covers Northern Ireland), due to the need to collect biometric data (fingerprints), **you can no longer apply for a visa through the Honorary Consulate in Belfast**. You have to apply at the Consulate in Edinburgh.

The site describes the procedure (including link to the booking system), required documentation, etc.